# LINQ - unable to flatten List of List

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to write a Linq query to get the identifiers of a particular object.  But it always returns IEnumerable List.  I tried to use SelectMany but it drills down inside the identifier object which i don't want.

This is my object with query

```
var DIDitems= from item in _configData.DocumentConfiguration
                                   where item.doctype == "Test"
                                   select item.ids;


public class DocumentType 
{
    [XmlAttribute("Value")]
    public string doctype { get; set; }

    public List<Identifier> ids { get; set; }
}


public class Identifier
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Path")]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Attribute")]
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
}
```

This is sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ConfigurationData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DocumentConfiguration>
    <DocumentType Value="Test">
      <ids>
        <Identifier Name="test" Path="test\test\test"  />
        <Identifier Name="test2" Path="test2\test2\test2"  />
      </ids>
    </DocumentType>
  </DocumentConfiguration>
</ConfigurationData>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Identifier> DIDItems = (from item in _configData.DocumentConfiguration
                      where item.doctype == "Test"
                      select item.ids.ToArray())
                    .SelectMany(r => r).ToList();
```

With method syntax you can do:

```
List<Identifier> DIDItems =_configData.DocumentConfiguration
                  .Where(r => r.doctype == "Test")
                  .SelectMany(r => r.ids)
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: np, thanks, I understand now I have to do SelectMany on the entire result which is of type IEnumerable<List<Identifier>>, I was trying to do SelectMany in the select item.ids which was wrong.

Comment: @erotavlas, For `SelectMany` it would be better if you use Method Syntax, because mixing it with query syntax, like my first code, doesn't look elegant, and `SelectMany` doesn't have a direct support in query syntax. *(Like Select/Where has)*.

Comment: understood, but the first example helped me visualize what is going on a bit better.

Comment: @erotavlas, yes that was the point to show that. With minimal changes it would provide you better understanding.

Comment: Is the `.ToArray()` needed? (in the first example)

Answer (score 6):

```
    var DIDItems =  _configData.DocumentConfiguration
       .Where(e => e.doctype == "Test")
       .SelectMany(e => e.ids).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 for being correct AND using the elegant syntax instead of the ugly query/method mix in the other correct answer.

Comment: here it is fixed now.